# Android Studio Annotate Git blame is not working

Tags: android-studio, radiance-flamingo

When I click with Annotate with Git blame is not working. It's connected to my Git. Just Updated with the latest AS. It does not show the dev's name. It used to show earlier. I use Source Tree tool.

[image: Android Studio version]